# php - How can I check if the sentence consists of a single word?

Tags: php, laravel-5

For example;

```
"Real Madrid" -> false
"Barcelona  " -> true
```

with what functions can I solve this in laravel?

Comment: You're looking for `strpos` (and `trim`).

Comment: Use a Laravel helper: [Str::wordCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-word-count)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use

```
$result = explode(' ', trim("barcelona "));
print_r($result);
```

trim will remove all white space at the beginning and the end of your string

Answer (score -1):

A string is a single word if it:

1. contains at least one character
2. contains no whitespace

```php
function isSingleWord(string $input): bool
{
    // Check for empty string - "" isn't a word
    if (empty($input)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check for whitespace of any kind
    return !preg_match('/\s/', $input);
}
```